# Export dataframes in list as worksheets in Excel file

Tags: r, dataframe

Should be a simple task, but I'm so far unable to find how.

**Sample data:**

```
var1 <- list('2003' = 1:3, '2004' = c(4:3), '2005' = c(6,4,1), '2006' = 1:4 )
```

**Unsuccessful code:**

```
library("XLConnect")
wb <- loadWorkbook("var1.xlsx", create = TRUE)
wb <- lapply(var1, function(x) {createSheet(wb, name = x)})
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Comment: Please specify what output you're expecting. You never write any data, which would use writeWorksheet or writeNamedRegion calls.

Comment: I expect to see worksheets with names '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006'. Column A in '2003' should have A1=1, A2=2, A3=3; '2004' should have A1='4', A2='3'; and so on. But you're right, I overlooked writing. Will look into it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A more concise version of @Andrie's answer, since the XLConnect API is vectorized:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("var1.xlsx", create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, names(var1))
writeWorksheet(wb, var1, names(var1),header=FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```