# Function to save R list into separate Excel worksheets

Tags: r, function, dataframe, export-to-excel

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257865/export-dataframes-in-list-as-worksheets-in-excel-file) I got a script that exports a list as separate worksheets in an Excel file (code as below). Now I would like to wrap it in a convenient function to reproduce this behavior by providing the input list name and output file name.

**Sample data:**

```
var1 <- list('2003' = 1:3, '2004' = c(4:3), '2005' = c(6,4,1), '2006' = 1:4 )
```

**Current script:**

```
require("XLConnect")
wb <- loadWorkbook("var1.xlsx", create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, names(var1))
writeWorksheet(wb, var1, names(var1),header=FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

**Disclaimer:** *While I blush to ask such a simple question, I'm sure many other visitors to SO will love to find this information here ;7)*

**EDIT :: ready-to-use function:**

```
save.excel <-function(.list, default = 'var1', path = ''){
    require("XLConnect")
    .name <- as.list(match.call())[2]
    if(is.language(.name[[1]])) wb_name <- paste0(paste0(path, default, collapse = '/'), '.xlsx')
    if(is.symbol(.name[[1]])) wb_name <- paste0(paste0(path, as.character(.name), collapse = '/'), '.xlsx')
    wb <- loadWorkbook(wb_name, create = TRUE)
    createSheet(wb, names(.list))
    writeWorksheet(wb,.list, names(.list),header=FALSE)
    saveWorkbook(wb)
    }
```

*The only difference from the solution below is that I added XLConnect as a library requested from inside the function, in case you didn't do it manually before ;7)*

Comment: There are no data.frames in your example code, just a named list

Comment: Have you read the help file for `writeNamedRegion`

Comment: @mnel, thanks. Second time in 2 consecutive days that I make that typo. **blush**

Comment: @mnel, yes I did. At the moment I'm struggling with writing functions, not with XLConnect.

Comment: @dmvianna the title of the question suggest you are looking for a function to save stuff to Excel, but isn't your real question how to wrap a set of commands into a function?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, I do need to save stuff to Excel. It is true that I expected something simpler than mnel's comprehensive solution, else I would not have blushed. But I'm happy with his response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is untested, as XLConnect will not install on my machine. but something like the following might work

## Simple approach

A function with two arguments

- `my_list` - the list which you wish to export elements of as separate worksheets
- `wb_name` - the name of the workbook

The function looks like this

```
write_list <-function(my_list, wb_name = 'var1.xlsx') {    
  wb <- loadWorkbook(wb_name, create = TRUE)
  createSheet(wb, names(my_list))
  writeWorksheet(wb, my_list, names(my_list),header=FALSE)
  saveWorkbook(wb)
 }
```

## fancy option that will use the name of the list

If you want to use the name of the `list` to create the file then you can have fun with 
`match.call`, `is.symbol` and `is.language`. Details of why you do this are below

```
write_list_name <-function(.list, default = 'var1', path = ''){
  .name <- as.list(match.call())[2]
   if(is.language(.name[[1]])){
     wb_name <- sprintf("%s/%s.xlsx", path, default)
   }
   if(is.symbol(.name[[1]])) {
    wb_name <- sprintf("%s/%s.xlsx", path, as.character(.name))
   }
  wb <- loadWorkbook(wb_name, create = TRUE)
  createSheet(wb, names(.list))
  writeWorksheet(wb,.list, names(.list),header=FALSE)
  saveWorkbook(wb)
  }
```

the `is.language` / `is.symbol` /`match.call` deal with the two situations

```
write_list_name(var1)

#in which case .name[[1]] is the symbol var1
```

and

```
write_list_name(list(n=2:3))
# in which case .name[[1]] is list(n=2:3), and class language 
# a file called list(n=2:3).xlsx would be not ideal, hence the `default` argument.
```

Comment: Deducing the name of the worksheet from the object name (if possible), imo distracts a bit from the problem of the OP. In a more simple, and illustrative imo, example the user can specify the name of the xlsx file, i.e. use `wb_name` as an argument.

Comment: In addition, you could replace the double `paste0` code by a single call to `sprintf`: e.g. `sprintf("%s/%s.xlsx", path, default)`.

Comment: Yes, it is perhaps gilding the lily or over egging the pudding (find appropriate idiom). I've edited the  answer

Comment: @mnel +1 for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solution of @mnel, here is some general information about functions.

In general, a function looks something like this:

```
function_name = function(input_a, input_b) {
    c = input_a * 2
    d = do_something(input_b)
    return(list(c, d))
}
```

where `input_a`, and `input_b` are the input arguments, and `list(c, d)` is the return value. This return value is assigned to the object which is on the left hand side of the `=` when calling the function:

```
out_a = function_name(a, b)
```

note that in the function body of `function_name`, `a` and `b` replace `input_a` and `input_b`. The fact that `a` is linked to `input_a` is done based on the order of the arguments. Alternatively, one can use named arguments:

```
out_a = function(input_a = a, input_b = b)
```

this makes the function call more readable in my opinion, especially for well chosen function and argument names.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs an up-to-date option, use `openxlsx`, directly call `write.xlsx` as follows:

```
var1 <- list('2003' = 1:3, '2004' = c(4:3), '2005' = c(6,4,1), '2006' = 1:4 )
write.xlsx(var1,"test.xlsx")
```